# "Тише едешь () дальше будешь" — знак препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в пословице "Тише едешь () дальше будешь" ставится тире или запятая? Я бы поставила тире.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну и правильно. Первая часть содержит условие того, о чем говорится во второй.